# this.$refs points to a vue component in a class styled component

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

Using package `vue-property-decorator`.

Component contents:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <label ref="label">asd</label>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
class Someclass extends Vue {
  public $refs!: {
    label: HTMLElement
  }

  private mounted(): void {
    console.log(this.$refs.label) // returns a Vue component, instead of just html
  }
}
</script>
```

It's because of `this` pointing to a class itself probably. But, how do i access `this.$refs.label`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put a `ref` on a Vue component, its DOM element can be accessed like this:

```
this.$refs.label.$el
```

`this.$refs.label` is a Vue instance and its [API is described here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Instance-Properties).

Regarding the ref attribute:

> ref is used to register a reference to an element or a child component. The reference will be registered under the parent component’s $refs object. If used on a plain DOM element, the reference will be that element; if used on a child component, the reference will be component instance.

## Update

Indeed, your example uses a label element, not a component. I assumed that you didn't show the whole code in the question and quoted the relevant parts of the doc. As you can see below, your code doesn't output what you say it does.

```js
Vue.component('my-component', {
  template: '<div><label ref="label">asd</label></div>',
  
  mounted() {
    const ref = this.$refs.label;
    console.log(ref);
    console.log("typeof(ref): " + typeof(ref));
    console.log("Is component: " + (ref instanceof Vue));
    console.log("Is HTMLElement: " + (ref instanceof HTMLElement));
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <my-component />
</div>
```

Comment: But in my case it's just a label

Comment: when you use this inside a class - it's a different story, without typescript and class syntax, my refs work as intended.

Comment: @AlexanderKim I don't know anything about class syntax then sorry. Perhaps you should rework your question more around the differences between the "normal" `this.$refs` and the class syntax with typescript.